# Electron + Node + SQLite: 'no such table: files'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

In electron front end, I have a button that successfully invokes a backend function to write to the db. Using this statement

```
const stmt = db.prepare(
    `INSERT INTO files (filename, path, tags_auto, tags_manual, object) VALUES ("Name of files", "Path of files", "auto", "manual", "object item")`
)
```

gives this error

```
SqliteError: no such table: files
    at Database.exec (G:\Dev\phyle\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\methods\wrappers.js:9:14)
    at exports.storeFiles (G:\Dev\phyle\src\sqlite\dbFiles.js:16:22)
    at AsyncFunction.getTree (G:\Dev\phyle\src\preload.js:38:10)
```

`"better-sqlite3": "^8.0.1",` wrapper for sqlite3.

Setup invoked with

```
const db = require('better-sqlite3')('./phyle.db', { fileMustExist: true })
```

I have already build a database using sqlite studio (file.db) with "files" table, other tables, with primary keys and what not. I put one row in the `files` table, but every table produces it's own "no such table" error.

The error does not change with or without `fileMustExist` flag, with or without a valid `file.db` file. There are constraints on the tables, but theyve been filled/changed since getting this message.

Bottom line is that the table is there, but this thinks it isn't.

What could be causing it to believe the tables isn't there?

Comment: hard to tell without the DDL which created your database. What does return the `.schema` when using the sqlite3 binary with your database ?

Comment: @davidriod what hhappened was that sqlite had created a .db file in the root of the project before I started using `fileMustExist` and I simply hadn't noticed. Fun fact: better-sqlite3 documentation says nothing about where a default file would be created.